# How to find deleted files when system restore is too "recent" to allow this?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I am using Windows 7, I am trying to find old files deleted roughly one year ago. I have tried to restore the folders they were in, but can not go farther back than October this year. My oldest system restore is currently at October 26 2014, and several at November 11 2014. Is there any way to find a log of all system restores done in the history of my computer and to be able to use one?

Comment: System restore only do exactly that, system restore to some time in the past. If the old files are your personal data, system restore will not restore those.

Comment: System restore restores the system. Backups restore your files/settings. This is why backups are important - if you don't have them, you can find yourself in trouble like this and be unable to recover data.